# DNN (DotNetNuke) 9.4.1 Install

Tags: installation

I am trying to get to grips with DNN so that I can upgrade it from a very old version to something newer.

I am running a new install of 9.4.1 and seem to be coming across 2 distinct error that I really cannot find anything about.

Error 1 - When I run the install website local, I get 54% ERROR:Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.AuthCookies_Update'.

HAs anyone else had this, and how did you get around it, I have tried this a number of times, and on both my local machine and a UAT server I have available.

Error 2 - One suggestion I found was to manually run the build.ps1 before running the install, however, when I do that, I get  Can't find the .git directory in D:....

Again, if anyone has tried this way of solving the above, how did you get round this.

I did try to manually add a .git folder, but this made no difference

Any help would be very gratefully received.

Comment: Can you find the stored procedure anywhere in the database?

Comment: Hi David, no I have looked, I have created a new blank database and let the install do everything.

Comment: I don't understand, is this stored procedure existing or not?

Comment: Sorry, no the stored procedure is not in the database, no matter how many times I clear and start again, or re download the install from the website, that SP does not appear in the database.

Comment: Maybe check the database log while installing.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get a chance to respond yesterday.  The error is coming up as part of the initial install, so nothing is showing in the SQL logs, there is also nothing in the install logs either, only that failure notice, my guess would be that as part of the install it needs to do something with regards to the SP, but as it does not exist, it can't.  I was hoping that this had been an issue for someone else and they had found=d a way round it.